# Weird results on a diffusion equation with Neumann conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I got this diffusion problem:

\begin{equation}
u_t-\alpha u_{xx}=0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0<x<L, t>0\\
u_x(0,t)=u_x(L,t)=0\\
u(x)=\begin{cases}
0\ \ \ \ \ 0<x<L/2\\
1\ \ \ \ \ L/2<x<L
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Here we can form the ansatz $u(x,t)=u(t)\cos\frac{n\pi}{L}x$, which we insert in the original PDE and obtain $u(t)=Ce^{(-\alpha\frac{n\pi}{L})^2}$.

The general solution is clearly

\begin{equation}
u_n(x,t)=Ce^{(-\alpha\frac{n\pi}{L})^2t}\cos\frac{n\pi}{L}x
\end{equation}

Forming a Fourier series of the solution, we have:

\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\alpha_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n e^{(-\alpha\frac{n\pi}{L})^2t}\cos\frac{n\pi}{L}x
\end{equation}

where we use the IC:

\begin{equation}
u(x,0)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n e^{0}\cos\frac{n\pi}{L}x
\end{equation}

Therefore, we can readily calculate the coefficient on that interval $L/2-L$ and get:

\begin{equation}
\alpha_n=\frac{2}{L/2}\int_{L/2}^L 1\cdot \cos\frac{n\pi}{L}xdx=0
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\alpha_0=\frac{2}{L/2}\int_{L/2}^L 1dx=1
\end{equation}

Something is clearly wrong here, but all looks correct. What did I miss?

Any help appreciated.